# How do I pass instances of objects to a function?

Tags: javascript, oop

I'm creating a multiplayer quizz game. I have started by creating a constructor function to store both the IDs of the players and the answer to each question (it's one question per letter of the alphabet):

```
function players(_id, a , b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o, p, q, r, s, t, u, v, w, x, y, z) {
this._id = _id;
this.a = a;
this.b = b;
this.c = c;
this.d = d;
this.e = e;
this.f = f;
this.g = g;
this.h = h;
this.i = i;
... etc.
```

I have put this all in a for loop that creates as many new players(obj) as the user inputs says. Then I have a different function for the questions. I'm having trouble figuring out how to pass each instance of the object players to the function. So let's say there's four players, I would want to pass players.id of Player 1 to the function, but I have no idea how to go about it.

What I'm doing at the moment is:

```
function createPlayers(playersTotal) {
numPlayers = playersTotal;
var num = "1"
for (var i = 0; i < numPlayers; i++) {
    var player = new players("Jugador " + num++);
    }
    questions(player);
}

function questions(obj) {

    console.log(obj);
}
```

Here's a snippet:

```js
function players(_id, a , b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o, p, q, r, s, t, u, v, w, x, y, z) {
    this._id = _id;
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
    this.c = c;
    this.d = d;
    this.e = e;
    this.f = f;
    this.g = g;
    this.h = h;
    this.i = i;
}

function createPlayers(playersTotal) {
    numPlayers = playersTotal;
    var num = "1"
    for (var i = 0; i < numPlayers; i++) {
        var player = new players("Jugador " + num++);
    }
    questions(player);
}

function questions(obj) {

    console.log(obj);
}

createPlayers(10);
```

But that only returns:

```
players {_id: "Jugador 4", a: undefined, b: undefined, c: undefined, d: undefined, …}
```

And that's another thing I'm doing wrong: overriding the player _id. So I guess my issue here is I can't figure out how to manage new instances of objects.

Any help or hint would be much appreciated.

Comment: What is `questions` expected to do? Ask all questions to one player? Ask one question to all players? Ask all questions to all players?

Comment: There are 25 questions in total, one per each letter. Each question can only be answered correctly once. So if you get A right, you continue until you fail one. If you fail C, Player 2 will have to start from C.

Comment: So you have `questions` implemented? Can you add the code for it to your question

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your call to `questions` is *outside* the loop creating players. So you're overwriting `player` repeatedly in the loop, then using only the last one. Put the call to `questions` **inside** the loop if you want to call it with each player:

```js
function players(_id, a , b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o, p, q, r, s, t, u, v, w, x, y, z) {
    this._id = _id;
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
    this.c = c;
    this.d = d;
    this.e = e;
    this.f = f;
    this.g = g;
    this.h = h;
    this.i = i;
}

function createPlayers(playersTotal) {
    numPlayers = playersTotal;
    var num = "1"
    for (var i = 0; i < numPlayers; i++) {
        var player = new players("Jugador " + num++);
        questions(player);
    }
}

function questions(obj) {

    console.log(obj);
}

createPlayers(10);
```

Or if you want to pass **all** the players to `questions` at once, you want to create an array of players and then pass that array to `questions`:

```js
function players(_id, a , b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o, p, q, r, s, t, u, v, w, x, y, z) {
    this._id = _id;
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
    this.c = c;
    this.d = d;
    this.e = e;
    this.f = f;
    this.g = g;
    this.h = h;
    this.i = i;
}

function createPlayers(playersTotal) {
    numPlayers = playersTotal;
    var num = "1"
    var playerList = []; // *** Create the array
    for (var i = 0; i < numPlayers; i++) {
        var player = new players("Jugador " + num++);
        playerList.push(player); // *** Put this player in it
    }
    questions(playerList); // *** Pass the array to the function
}

function questions(obj) {

    console.log(obj);
}

createPlayers(10);
```

---

There are a couple of other problems with the code, and other things you might consider changing:

1. `numPlayers` is never declared. In loose mode (which you appear to be using), that maens your code is falling prey to what I call *The Horror of Implicit Globals*, creating a **global** `numPlayers` variable (not one confined to `createPlayers`). Be sure to declare your variables.
2. You're initializing `num` with a **string**, `"1"`, but then using `++` on it, which will convert it to a number. Initialize it with a number instead (`var num = 1;`) so it's consistent.
3. **But**, you don't need `num`; you already have `i`. You could just do `new players(i + 1);` Or even make the loop `for (i = 1; i <= numPlayers; ++i)` and use `new players(i)`.
4. In JavaScript, the overwhelming conventions with constructor functions *(ones meant to be called with `new`) are:

   - They start with a capital letter, so `Players`, not `players`; and
   - They're singular nouns, not plural nouns (except in some edge cases), so `Player`, not `players`.